# Where do you view pull requests made in git?

Tags: powershell, git

I am learning git. I made some legitimately useful VBA code commits on github while at work and I cloned the repos on my local machine after hours in order to learn Git and Version Control. I made the repos several different ways, including with with PowerShell, SourceTree, Github Desktop and Visual Studio just to be able to compare, but I only modified the repo and pushed back out on the terminal (PowerShell) here at home. The rest I let stay.

Back at work next day I made changes on the website, and I made a pull request with respect to the master branch (from "optimized" branch, which was a refactoring of the code project for more speed). I didn't really need a pull request because it's only me on different repos, but I wanted to learn how it works.

I tried finding this answer via the docs and google but it's returning null.

What I'm expect is to use the "git status" command or some similar command in PowerShell that alerts me to the fact there's a pull request out there. What good is a PR if nobody gets the memo? They seem to take for granted it comes to you. I tried checking out both branches

So how do I tell PowerShell to report pull requests for me from the remote repo (github.com)? Seems like it should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Git alone doesn't really have its own built-in system for pull requests. (Originally – as in the linux.git repository – "pull requests" were exchanged by regular email. They were literally just messages asking the maintainer to `git pull` this branch from that repository URL.)

In most situations, when you're dealing with pull requests (or 'merge requests') it's usually taken care of by the hosting provider – e.g. by GitHub – and is not something that would show up in "git status" at all. (Though there *are* CLI addons which let you use GitHub from the command line, such as [hub](https://andrewlock.net/creating-github-pull-requests-from-the-command-line-with-hub/).)

[image: Screenshot of GitHub's list of pull requests]

So when you open a pull request on GitHub or BitBucket, the hosting provider usually **sends an email message** to the repository's owners, as well as showing a notification on the website itself. And if you're using e.g. the "GitHub Desktop" app, I believe it shows the same notifications through the app as well.

[image: Screenshot of email message on Gmail informing about a pull request]

As for actually accessing those pull requests through CLI – it depends on the provider, but most of them support downloading incoming PRs through `git fetch`. And in any case you can just get the corresponding branch straight from the submitter's own "fork" repository. (But most Git hosting providers support merging PRs automatically on the server, so often you just review it on the website and click the green button.)